# Haw I can set running time in java Spring server?

Tags: java, spring, maven, web, websocket

I have a problem with a websocket because client time and server time doesn't match.
How can I set the local time of a java-spring server. I used maven dependencies. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change local time zone to be same as your client has. 
you can

- system property -Duser.timezone=America/New_York
- or environment TZ="Europe/Bratislava"
- or code

```
ZoneId bratislavaZoneId = ZoneId.of("Europe/Bratislava");
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(bratislavaZoneId);
TimeZone.setDefault(tz);
SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class);
```